# PHP CURL netsuite API throws invalid login and login audit throws invalidSignature in netsuite

Tags: magento2, php, rest-api, netsuite

I am trying to get customers from NetSuite API in Magento. It throws error

```
{"type":"https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.2","title":"Invalid login attempt, for more details see Login Audit Trail.","status":401,"o:errorCode":"INVALID_LOGIN"}
```

I checked in the error log in Netsuite. Over there error is invalidSignature.

Please guys help me Where am I going to wrong?
I had checked the 10 times signature method process on different websites, but it still says,u the OAuth signature is invalid.

Please Help me, Developers.
If any developer has a doubt feel free to ask a question in detail
Here is code

```
<?php
        
    define("NETSUITE_URL", 'https://xxxxxxxxx.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customer/1');
    define("NETSUITE_ACCOUNT", 'xxxxxxx');
    define("NETSUITE_CONSUMER_KEY", 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    define("NETSUITE_CONSUMER_SECRET", 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    define("NETSUITE_TOKEN_ID", 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    define("NETSUITE_TOKEN_SECRET", 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');     
    
    $oauth_nonce = md5(mt_rand());
    $oauth_timestamp = time();
    $oauth_signature_method = 'HMAC-SHA1';
    $oauth_version = "1.0";
        
    $baseString = urlencode(NETSUITE_URL)."&".urlencode(
           "&oauth_consumer_key=".NETSUITE_CONSUMER_KEY
            ."&oauth_nonce=".$oauth_nonce
            ."&oauth_signature_method=".$oauth_signature_method
            ."&oauth_timestamp=".$oauth_timestamp
            ."&oauth_token=".NETSUITE_TOKEN_ID
            ."&oauth_version=".$oauth_version
          );

   $sigString = urlencode(NETSUITE_CONSUMER_SECRET).'&'.urlencode(NETSUITE_TOKEN_SECRET);
   $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $baseString, $sigString, true));
    
   $auth_header = "OAuth "
          . 'oauth_signature="' . $signature . '", '
          . 'oauth_version="' . rawurlencode($oauth_version) . '", '
          . 'oauth_nonce="' . rawurlencode($oauth_nonce) . '", '
          . 'oauth_signature_method="' . rawurlencode($oauth_signature_method) . '", '
          . 'oauth_consumer_key="' . rawurlencode(NETSUITE_CONSUMER_KEY) . '", '
          . 'oauth_token="' . rawurlencode(NETSUITE_TOKEN_ID) . '", '  
          . 'oauth_timestamp="' . rawurlencode($oauth_timestamp) . '", '
          . 'realm="' . rawurlencode(NETSUITE_ACCOUNT) .'"';
      
        
    $curl = curl_init();
    
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => NETSUITE_URL,
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      // CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => true,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=>false,
      CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=>false,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
       CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Authorization:$auth_header"
      ),
     
    ));
    
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    
    curl_close($curl);
    echo $response;    
    
?>
```

Comment: Hey man, did you solve this? how?

Comment: @ezequielfernandez yes I solved it

Comment: Could you please let me know how? I've been fighting with this and nothing. .its not working form me

Comment: @ezequielfernandez ok sure I will post the answer here soon so do not worry

Comment: @EzequielFernandez I posted the answer please check it. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my code which I am using to connect with Netsuite.
If anyone has question, feel free to ask me because I did a lot struggle to understand NetSuite API and its structure.

```
<?php

    class callNetsuiteApi{
        
         // PRODUCTION CREDENTIALS
        const NETSUITE_CONSUMER_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        const NETSUITE_ACCOUNT = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        const NETSUITE_CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        const NETSUITE_TOKEN_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
        const NETSUITE_TOKEN_SECRET = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; 
        
        public function callRestApi($url){
  
        $oauth_nonce = md5(mt_rand());
        $oauth_timestamp = time();
        $oauth_signature_method = 'HMAC-SHA256';
        $oauth_version = "1.0";
        
        // generate Signature 
        $baseString = $this->restletBaseString("GET",
        $url,
        self::NETSUITE_CONSUMER_KEY,
        self::NETSUITE_TOKEN_ID,
        $oauth_nonce,
        $oauth_timestamp,
        $oauth_version,
        $oauth_signature_method,null);
        
        
        $key = rawurlencode(self::NETSUITE_CONSUMER_SECRET) .'&'. rawurlencode(self::NETSUITE_TOKEN_SECRET);
    
    
         $signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $baseString, $key, true)); 
         
         // GENERATE HEADER TO PASS IN CURL
         $header = 'Authorization: OAuth '
                 .'realm="' .rawurlencode(self::NETSUITE_ACCOUNT) .'", '
                 .'oauth_consumer_key="' .rawurlencode(self::NETSUITE_CONSUMER_KEY) .'", '
                 .'oauth_token="' .rawurlencode(self::NETSUITE_TOKEN_ID) .'", '
                 .'oauth_nonce="' .rawurlencode($oauth_nonce) .'", '
                 .'oauth_timestamp="' .rawurlencode($oauth_timestamp) .'", '
                 .'oauth_signature_method="' .rawurlencode($oauth_signature_method) .'", '
                 .'oauth_version="' .rawurlencode($oauth_version) .'", '
                 .'oauth_signature="' .rawurlencode($signature) .'"';
             
             
        return  $this->callCurl($header,$url);
    
        }
        public function callCurl($header,$url){
                $curl = curl_init();
    
            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
              CURLOPT_URL => $url,
              CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
              CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
              CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
              CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
              CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
              CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
              CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=>false,
              CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=>false,
              CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
               CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
               $header,
               "content-type: application/json"
              ),
             
            ));
    
            $response = curl_exec($curl);
    
            curl_close($curl);
    
            $product = json_decode($response, true);
            return $product;        
        }
        public function restletBaseString($httpMethod, $url, $consumerKey, $tokenKey, $nonce, $timestamp, $version, $signatureMethod, $postParams){
              //http method must be upper case
              $baseString = strtoupper($httpMethod) .'&';
              
              //include url without parameters, schema and hostname must be lower case
              if (strpos($url, '?')){
                $baseUrl = substr($url, 0, strpos($url, '?'));
                $getParams = substr($url, strpos($url, '?') + 1);
              } else {
               $baseUrl = $url;
               $getParams = "";
              }
              $hostname = strtolower(substr($baseUrl, 0,  strpos($baseUrl, '/', 10)));
              $path = substr($baseUrl, strpos($baseUrl, '/', 10));
              $baseUrl = $hostname . $path;
              $baseString .= rawurlencode($baseUrl) .'&';
              
              //all oauth and get params. First they are decoded, next alphabetically sorted, next each key and values is encoded and finally whole parameters are encoded
              $params = array();
              $params['oauth_consumer_key'] = array($consumerKey);
              $params['oauth_token'] = array($tokenKey);
              $params['oauth_nonce'] = array($nonce);
              $params['oauth_timestamp'] = array($timestamp);
              $params['oauth_signature_method'] = array($signatureMethod);
              $params['oauth_version'] = array($version);
               
              foreach (explode('&', $getParams ."&". $postParams) as $param) {
                $parsed = explode('=', $param);
                if ($parsed[0] != "") {
                  $value = isset($parsed[1]) ? urldecode($parsed[1]): "";
                  if (isset($params[urldecode($parsed[0])])) {
                    array_push($params[urldecode($parsed[0])], $value);
                  } else {
                    $params[urldecode($parsed[0])] = array($value);
                  }
                }
              }
               
              //all parameters must be alphabetically sorted
              ksort($params);
               
              $paramString = "";
              foreach ($params as $key => $valueArray){
                //all values must be alphabetically sorted
                sort($valueArray);
                foreach ($valueArray as $value){
                  $paramString .= rawurlencode($key) . '='. rawurlencode($value) .'&';
                }
              }
              $paramString = substr($paramString, 0, -1);
               $baseString .= rawurlencode($paramString);
              
              return $baseString;
            }
    }

$obj = new callNetsuiteApi();
    $url = "https://xxxxxxxxx.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/inventoryItem/".$internalId."?expandSubResources=true";
    $response = $obj->callRestApi($url);
    ?>
```

Comment: You are the best! Thank you

Comment: No problem anytime I will help and I will share all the netsuite tutorials regarding netsuite in near future

Comment: rockstar, thanks a ton :) do you also have an implementation for Netsuite order status syncing?

Comment: @Wolfack welcome, no because we are using celigo order flow

Comment: @Wolfack if this answer help you, please up vote for encourage,for more rest api tutorial you can visit here https://medium.com/@soni.manthan0

Comment: @NirajPatel Thank you soo much for the code. I got stuck from last 2 weeks finally it's working.  Thank you once again. You have any tutorials for this?

Comment: @matheenulla I am glad your code is working, actually I found one post year ago on netsuite support page unfortunately that page is dead now, that page was about connection with netsuite rest api from any platform, do you want tutorials for suiteQL or netsuite REST API ?

Comment: @NirajPatel Netsuite REST API tutorials will be helpfull to integrate

Comment: @matheenulla https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_1545141500.html
and here is the list of schema
https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/APIs/REST_API_Browser/record/v1/2022.1/index.html#tag-inventoryItem

Comment: @NirajPatel Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

HI Niraj thanks for your support , given below source code used by me:
Step-1st: getting the payload in json-formate from stripe
Step-2nd: Using TBA process to push the payload in Net-suite.

```
require_once('./configration.php');//get netsuite key info
require_once('./stripe-php-master/init.php'); // setup of stripe 
$endpoint_secret = CUSTOMER_WEB_HOOK_ENDPOINT_SECRET;

$payload = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$sig_header = $_SERVER['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE'];
$event = null;
/**
 * Log File Validation Start
 */
$log_file_size=5242880; //10MB
if( file_exists('customer.log') && (filesize('customer.log') > $log_file_size) ){    
  rename("customer.log","customer_".date("Y-m-d").".log");
  file_put_contents('customer.log','Log File Created on:: '.date("Y-m-d"), FILE_APPEND);//New file created  

}elseif( !file_exists('customer.log')){
  $content='New Log File Created on ::'.date("Y-m-d");
  $fp = fopen('customer.log', 'w');
  fwrite($fp, $content);
  fclose($fp);
  chmod('./customer.log', 777);
}

/**
 * Getting Stripe Data 
 */
try {
    $event = \Stripe\Webhook::constructEvent($payload, $sig_header, $endpoint_secret);
  } catch (\UnexpectedValueException $e) {
    file_put_contents('customer.log', "ERROR-1 [".date("Y.m.d")."]::DATA:: ".$e."  \n", FILE_APPEND);
    http_response_code(400);
    exit();
  } catch (\Stripe\Exception\SignatureVerificationException $e) {
    file_put_contents('customer.log', "ERROR-2 [".date("Y.m.d")."]::DATA:: ".$e."  \n", FILE_APPEND);
    http_response_code(400);
    exit();
  }

  
//////////////////////////CURL to get Access token /////////////////////////////////
$NONCE_SECRET   = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 11);
$NONCE_SECRET   = uniqid(mt_rand(1, 1000));
$oauth_timestamp= time();
$oauth_nonce    = $NONCE_SECRET;

$url            ="https://xxx-sb1.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl?script=1091&deploy=1";
$base_url       ="https://xxx-sb1.restlets.api.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/restlet.nl";
$consumerKey    ="xxxx";
$consumerSecret ="xxxx";
$accessToken    ="xxxx";
$tokenSecret    ="xxxx";
$signatureMethod="HMAC-SHA256";
$version        ="1.0";
$script_id      ="1091";
$realm          ="XXXXX_SB1";
$httpMethod     ="POST";

$base_string = $httpMethod . '&' . rawurlencode($url) . "&"
    . rawurlencode("oauth_consumer_key=" . rawurlencode($consumerKey)
    . "&oauth_nonce=" . rawurlencode($oauth_nonce)
    . "&oauth_signature_method=" . rawurlencode($signatureMethod)
    . "&oauth_timestamp=" . rawurlencode($oauth_timestamp)
    . "&oauth_token=" . rawurlencode($accessToken)
    . "&oauth_version=" . rawurlencode($version));

$key = rawurlencode($consumerSecret) .'&'. rawurlencode($tokenSecret);
$oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha256', $base_string, $key, true));

$header = array(
    "Authorization: OAuth
    realm=\"$realm\",oauth_consumer_key=\"$consumerKey\",oauth_token=\"$accessToken\",oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA256\",oauth_timestamp=\"$oauth_timestamp\",oauth_nonce=\"$oauth_nonce\",oauth_version=\"$version\",oauth_signature=\"$oauth_signature\"",
    "Cookie: NS_ROUTING_VERSION=LAGGING",
);          
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>json_encode($event),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
));
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$response = curl_exec($curl);
if($response===false){
    file_put_contents('customer.log', "Error 3[".date("Y.m.d")."]::'".curl_error($curl)."' \n  DATA:: ".json_encode($event)." \n", FILE_APPEND);
    http_response_code(403);
}else{
    $curlResponse = json_decode($response);
    if( $curlResponse === true ){
        http_response_code(200);
    }elseif( !empty($curlResponse->error->code) && $curlResponse->error->code === 'INVALID_LOGIN_ATTEMPT' ){
        file_put_contents('customer.log', "ERROR-4: [".date("Y.m.d :: h:i:sa")."]::".json_encode($response)." \n", FILE_APPEND);
        http_response_code(403);
    }else{
        file_put_contents('customer.log', "ERROR-5: [".date("Y.m.d :: h:i:sa")."]::".json_encode($response)." \n", FILE_APPEND);
        http_response_code(403);
    }
}
curl_close($curl);



////////////////////PAYLOAD SAMPLE///////////////////
{
    "id":"cus_N8zKRT00ihPFl5",
    "object":"customer",
    "address":{
       "city":"billingCity",
       "country":"IN",
       "line1":"billing address line 1",
       "line2":"billing address line 2",
       "postal_code":"123456",
       "state":"DL"
     },
     "balance":0,
     "created":1673355261,
     "currency":"inr",
     "default_source":null,
     "delinquent":false,
     "description":"Description Description ",
     "discount":null,
     "email":"account@email.com",
     "invoice_prefix":"INVOICEPREFI",
     "invoice_settings":{
       "custom_fields":null,
       "default_payment_method":null,
       "footer":null,
       "rendering_options":null
     },
     "livemode":false,
     "metadata":[],
     "name":"customer name",
     "next_invoice_sequence":2,
     "phone":"+91999999999",
     "preferred_locales":["en-US"],
     "shipping":{
       "address":{
          "city":"shippingCity",
          "country":"RU",
          "line1":"shipping address line 1",
          "line2":"shipping address line 2",
          "postal_code":"258741",
          "state":"\u041a\u0435\u043c\u0435\u0440\u043e\u0432\u0441\u043a\u0430\u044f \u043e\u0431\u043b\u0430\u0441\u0442\u044c"
      },
      "name":"shipping Name",
      "phone":"+99999999"
    },
    "tax_exempt":"none",
    "test_clock":null
  }
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/206590)

Comment: Better if u  answer for this

Comment: @user9061866 sure I will help you but I do not know what exactly code are you using, please post a question with specific error so I can give you answer fast

Comment: @NirajPatel i have updated the query plz let me know if any thing else required from my side ( getting error - INVALID_SIGNATURE in netsuite)

Comment: Please try to copy exact my accepted answer code and try it

Comment: @NirajPatel, still facing same issues with your code,  its working only in case of "GET" not in "POST" method, please let me know your solution

Comment: @NirajPatel, thanks final i got the solution, after a single line modification its working, my end also for 'POST' with 'JSON' payload

Comment: @user9061866  glad to hear

Answer (score 0):

thx for sharing - this is great
what about using this for POST and SuiteQL - body needed to be passed like

{
"q": "select * from billingSchedule  where transaction is not null"
}

--data-raw "{
"q": "select * from billingSchedule  where transaction is not null"
}"